# Creating Rich Many-to-Many Associations in Rails Active Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm a beginner in rails and I'm studying Beginning Rails 4 3rd Edition:

I have 3 models for Rich Many-to-Many Association:

1- Comment

2- Article

3- User

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :body

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :comments

  def long_title
    "#{title} - #{published_at}"
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :articles, -> {order('published_at DESC, title ASC')},
                      :dependent => :nullify
  has_many :replies, :through => :articles, :source => :comments
end
```

The association works well in my opinion, but when I tried with rails console I have to close it and reopen it to get the changes applied, unless user.replies.empty? always is true.

Notice I tried `reload!` but still changes is not working until I reopen rails console.
Do you know why this behavior?

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem?

Comment: Why rails console need to be closed and reopened it to apply changes in Rich Many-to-Many associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what changes you're not seeing. If you change your code just call the `reload!` method:

```
irb(main):001:0> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
```

If you're changing data (through a Rails server, perhaps) while you have a running console, then calling `reload` on your object is what you want:

```
user = User.first
# change some stuff in the database
user.reload
# user now has the changed data
```